# Default branch name for ansistrano (ansible) deployment

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am new at ansible and ansistrano.

I have successfully deployed by providing branch name as variable in yml file.

```
default_branch: "master"
ansistrano_git_branch: "{{default_branch}}"
```

Also providing branch name in extra-vars works.

```
ansistrano_git_branch: {{branch}}
ansible-playbook playbook-deploy.yml -i testing --extra-vars "branch=develop"
```

But how to provide default value if branch is not passed via extra-vars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fuse them together by using

```
default_branch: "master"
ansistrano_git_branch: "{{ branch | default(default_branch) }}"
```

or simply  omit the defaul_branch (extra variable) and write

```
ansistrano_git_branch: "{{ branch | default('master') }}"
```

Now both of the commands will work:

```
ansible-playbook playbook-deploy.yml -i testing --extra-vars "branch=develop"
```

and

```
ansible-playbook playbook-deploy.yml -i testing
```

**you can prompt for value:**

```
 vars_prompt:
    - name: branch
      prompt: 'Enter a branch to deploy'
      default: develop
      private: no
```

**Note:** ansible only prompts for branch if value is not provided through extra-vars.